# Custom ListView with images, from app installed

Tags: android, image, listview

Well I'm trying to make a `ListView` with images and text. I have been following this example: [Android: Custom ListView with Image and Text using ArrayAdapter](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/#ixzz2ACbmrnvf) BUT I want the list to be about installed apps and its icons. I have been following this other example to get the icons: [Get installed Applications with Name, Package Name, Version and Icon](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon)

I have been able to make the list, with icons, but can't get them from installed apps. If I use any pic from my drawable the code works perfectly. So the question is how can I get the icons and add them to my `ListView`?

The code is a little bit big, I will try to make it smaller and post it later. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well while trying to make it easy to read and post it here I found the solution. This is the magic code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.apps_list_view);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<AppListRowItem>();

    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);

        Pinfo newInfo = new Pinfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());

            PackageNames = p.packageName;

            AppNames = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();

        test = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());

        AppListRowItem item = new AppListRowItem(test, AppNames, PackageNames);
        rowItems.add(item);

    }
```

Everything else is just like the links posted above.

Comment: I believe it's good practice to mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for sharing the question, though.